# standard error on the slope from a linear regression

Tags: regression, standard-error, linear

Suppose you are running an experiment where you measure a (positive) variable $A$ of a given physical system at multiple times, say $t = \{ 0, 10, 20, 45, 90, 120, 180 \} \ min$, and calculate $y(t) = ln(A(t))-ln(A(0))$.
From the theory you expect $A(t) = A(0) \cdot exp(-k \cdot t)$, hence $y(t) = - k \cdot t$.
Your goal is to estimate the 'true' value of $k$, i.e. $k_{true}$.

If you knew nothing about the uncertainty on the individual measurements of $A(t)$, and were allowed to run the experiment only once, I guess the only option would be to do a linear regression on the experimental $(t,y(t))$ points (excluding $t=0$, of course, as it is forced) and report $k = -slope$, and its standard error $SE_k$, obtained from the regression itself.

However, suppose you *do* know, from historical data, that the standard deviation on $ln(A(t))$ is constant, independent from  $ln(A(t))$ itself, and equal to $s \approx 0.023$.
To be completely clear, by this I mean that if the measurement of $A(t)$ is repeated multiple times, its natural logarithm is found to be normally distributed around $ln(A(t))_{true}$, with a standard deviation equal to $0.023$, which does not change for different values of $t$ or of $k_{true}$.
[FYI, this is a 'real world' example: we did observe this in actual experiments].

I ran some simulations in R (see below) to find the distribution of $k$ estimated by regression, under the above hypothesis of constant standard deviation on each $ln(A(t))$.
It turned out that $k$ was normally distributed, with standard deviation $sd_k \approx 0.00016$, regardless of the value of $k_{true}$. Instead, $SE_k$ was, not unexpectedly, all over the place.

**So here is my doubt**: if you had to report an estimate for $k$ and its uncertainty, would you use the value of $SE_k$ from the regression (which for a single experiment could be quite off the mark), or would you use the knowledge of the standard deviation on $ln(A(t))$ to derive or simulate a 'theoretical' $sd_k$?

Here is the R code:

```
k_true = 0.012
cat("\nk_true =",k_true)
t = c(0,10,20,45,90,120,180)
A_true = exp(-k_true*t)

s = 0.023
n_rep = 5000

set.seed(97531)

ln_A_measured_rep <- sapply(A_true,function(x) rnorm(n = n_rep,mean = log(x),sd = s))

k_repls <- apply(ln_A_measured_rep,1,function(r) {
  d <- data.frame(x = t[-1], y = (r-r[1])[-1])
  l <- lm(y ~ x, d)
  sml <- summary(l)
  km <- -1*sml$coefficients[2]
  SE_km <- sml$coefficients[4] 
  return(c(km,SE_km))
  }
)

sd_k <- sd(k_repls[1,])

cat("\nsd_k =", sd_k)

hist(k_repls[2,],main="SE_k",xlab="SE_k")
abline(v=sd_k,col=2)
```

You can test that by changing $k_{true}$, $sd_k$ does not change.

I hope at least some of this makes sense; any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

**EDIT**: formula for the value of $sd_k$

After long calculations, I found that for any $N >= 2$, $N$ being the number of distinct time points at which $y(t)$ is measured:

$sd_k = \frac s {\sqrt {\sum_{i=1}^N {t_i^2} - \frac 1 N (\sum_{i=1}^N {t_i})^2}}$

In the above example:

$sd_k = \frac {0.023} {\sqrt {(10^2+20^2+45^2+90^2+120^2+180^2) - \frac 1 6 (10+20+45+90+120+180)^2}} = \frac {0.023} {\sqrt {57425 - 36037.5}} \approx 0.00016$

The derivation of the formula was theoretical; still, I tested it numerically on a large number of examples, changing $k_{true}$, $s$ and the number and positions of the time points sampled. It seems to work.

Comment: Is $A(0)$ measured?  If so, an important consideration is that all your $y$ values are interdependent, so the regression procedure ought to account for that.

Comment: you mentioned you had calculated $y(t) = ln(A(t)) - ln(A(0))$ but are calculating a linear regression. Shouldn't that be $y(t) = ln(A(t) - A(0))$ if you're trying to fit a generalized linear model, with $ln()$ as the link function?

Comment: @whuber : indeed, it is measured, and I do take that into account, by eliminating the $t=0$ point in the regression, as $y=0$ by definition for that point, so it's not free.

Comment: @Jack : $ln(A(t)-A(0)) = ln(A(0) \cdot (e^{-k \cdot t}-1)) = ln(A(0)) + ln(e^{-k \cdot t}-1))$. Then I would not know how to get $k$ from the regression. BTW, I spotted a mistake in my formula for $y(t)$, I will correct it.

Comment: Actually, it was not wrong.

Comment: You do not correctly account for the measurement, though, because it makes *all* the response variables interdependent. In particular, all your standard errors will be wrong.  (For the particular parameter values and values of $t$ you posit, they will only be about 9% low, but in other circumstances they could be more seriously underestimated.)

Comment: @whuber : unfortunately these are the data we get from the company that runs the experiment. We don't get A(t) (including A(0)), we just get the ratio's A(t)/A(0) for each t. My method consists in taking the $ln$ of each ratio (which is $y(t)$) and linearly relating it to $t$, because the theory says indeed that the relationship between the two is linear. If this method is wrong, what would be the correct one then? What would you do with these data?

Comment: That is an interesting question!

Comment: I tried replacing `d <- data.frame(x = t[-1], y = (r-r[1])[-1])` with `d <- data.frame(x = t, y = r)` in my simulation code above. The result was $sd_k \approx 0.00014$, again apparently independent from $k_{true}$. But in any case, my original simulation represents what we actually do with the data we get, so I was hoping it would be relevant.

Comment: All these months later, we are still discussing (at work) what the correct way to report the uncertainty on the slope should be. Any ideas anyone? Personally, I am still convinced that when you know the uncertainty on the individual $y(t)$'s and you know it's constant, you should use the calculated $sd_k$ to express the uncertainty on $k$, not the standard error from the regression $SE_k$. Not because I say so, but because I tested it by simulation, and I found that using $SE_k$ will most of the time overestimate or underestimate the uncertainty.